# How do i move a repository with LFS support to gitlab.com?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs

I have a repository on an old githost instance and i'm trying to migrate it over to gitlab.com. I'm using their instructions for migrating, but because this repository uses LFS, i am getting some errors that i cannot figure out how to resolve. Here are the commands I'm running

```
cd repo
git remote rename origin old-origin
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:group/repo.git
git push -u origin --all
git push -u origin --tags
```

And here is a sample of the response i get from `git` on the first `push` command:

```
remote: GitLab: LFS objects are missing. Ensure LFS is properly set up or try a manual "git lfs push --all".
To https://gitlab.com/group/repo.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/group/repo.git'
```

I have tried the suggested command (`git lfs push --all`) and that command is not valid. I have also tried `git lfs push origin master` and that results in:

```
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (29/29), 2.4 GB | 0 B/s, done
```

I cannot find anything on the Gitlab docs, so i'm asking for this community's help. Thanks!

Edit: I have also tried using `https` instead of SSH repo origin and that results in no difference.

Comment: How about pushing --mirror?   `git lfs push --mirror /remoteOnGitlab` like in this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528550/updating-and-repairing-lfs-when-migrating-repositories-from-github-to-selfhosted

Comment: How did you setup lfs for your project on gitlab.com ?

Comment: @g19fanatic Thank you. I did try these instructions, but they seem somewhat outdated and do not work. Specifically the final `git lfs push --mirror` command is no longer available. I tried without the `--mirror` option and i tried `git push --mirror …` and neither worked.

Comment: @LeGEC I enabled git lfs support via the toggle switch on the `General Settings > Permissions` page for the new project i'm trying to push to.

Answer (score 2):

I just attempted to do what you're trying to do.

Did the following:

- `git clone git@github.com:g19fanatic/test_lfs.git cd test_lfs`
- `git lfs track *.bin`
- `yes "123456678" | head -c 1024000 > test.bin`
- `git add .`
- `git push origin master`

  - saw the file in github, tracked with lfs
- `git remote add gitlab git@gitlab.com:pauldibiase/lfs-test.git`
- `git lfs push --all gitlab`

  - received the following error: 
    `Locking support detected on remote "gitlab". Consider enabling it with:   $ git config lfs.https://gitlab.com/pauldibiase/lfs-test.git/info/lfs.locksverify true`
- `git config lfs.https://gitlab.com/pauldibiase/lfs-test.git/info/lfs.locksverify true`
- `git lfs push --all gitlab`

  - Uploading LFS objects: 100% (1/1), 1.0 MB | 0 B/s, done
- `git push gitlab master`

  - saw file in gitlab, lfs tracked

> FIPS mode initialized
>
> Uploading LFS objects: 100% (1/1), 1.0 MB | 0 B/s, done
>
> Counting objects: 4, done.
>
> Delta compression using up to 16 threads.
>
> Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
>
> Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 416 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
>
> Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
>
> To git@gitlab.com:pauldibiase/lfs-test.git
>
> - [new branch]      master -> master

Using `git --version` = `git version 1.8.3.1`

Using `git lfs --version` = `git-lfs/2.6.1 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.11.2; git dc072c3e)`

Try to push your actual branch to your new gitlab remote.