# error: --mirror can't be combined with refspecs

Tags: git

I mirrored a git repository and deleted `application.properties` containing passwords from the `MyProject` repository. I can see the message under `Deleted files` and my file name below:

```
$ java -jar bfg-1.13.0.jar --delete-files application.properties --no-blob-protection MyProject.git

Using repo : \\hnas1-users\USERS\dan\Desktop\bfg_test_after_delete\MyProject.git

Found 0 objects to protect
Found 4 commit-pointing refs : HEAD, refs/heads/Single_home_page, refs/heads/Second_home_page, refs/heads/master

Protected commits
-----------------
You're not protecting any commits, which means the BFG will modify the contents of even *current* commits.
This isn't recommended - ideally, if your current commits are dirty, you should fix up your working copy and commit that, check that your build still works, and only then run the BFG to clean up your history.

Cleaning
--------

Found 862 commits
Cleaning commits:       100% (862/862)
Cleaning commits completed in 99,796 ms.

Updating 3 Refs
---------------

        Ref                             Before     After
        ---------------------------------------------------
        refs/heads/Single_home_page   | 7e099f8c | d4fa8bdc
        refs/heads/Second_home_page | 0145da48 | 1b9b1ca2
        refs/heads/master             | 0e8ac08e | 502363b0

Updating references:    100% (3/3)
...Ref update completed in 393 ms.

Commit Tree-Dirt History
------------------------

        Earliest                                              Latest
        |                                                          |
        DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD

        D = dirty commits (file tree fixed)
        m = modified commits (commit message or parents changed)
        . = clean commits (no changes to file tree)

                                Before     After
        -------------------------------------------
        First modified commit | 5a303ff3 | 0280ae15
        Last dirty commit     | 7e099f8c | d4fa8bdc

Deleted files
-------------

        Filename                 Git id
        -----------------------------------------------------------------
        application.properties | c5e94e15 (2.3 KB), b8f324fd (887 B), ...
```

I have following question and problem :

I have cloned my code using git mirror from the `Single_home_page` repository and Since there are 4 commit-pointing refs as shown above which are `HEAD, refs/heads/Single_home_page, refs/heads/Second_home_page, refs/heads/master`, I want to make sure that after deleting the above file, I push my changes to `Single_home_page` repository only. For this, I tried doing the following:

`git push origin Single_home_page` and `git push --set-upstream origin Single_home_page`
got the following error for both cases :

`error: --mirror can't be combined with refspecs`

What am I doing wrong here?

=====================================================================

Update on March 17th after following the steps mentioned in brian's answer:

After following the steps, I got the following :

```
 git push origin Single_home_page
To http://<path to git repo>/MyProject.git
 ! [rejected]        Single_home_page -> Single_home_page (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://<path to git repo>/MyProject.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

After using `+` for my branch:

```
 $ git push origin +Single_home_page
Counting objects: 10089, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4439/4439), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10089/10089), 32.84 MiB | 6.27 MiB/s, done.
Total 10089 (delta 5475), reused 6793 (delta 4329)
To http://<path to MyProject>/MyProject.git
 + 7e099f8...d4fa8bd Single_home_page -> Single_home_page (forced update)
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since you said that you mirrored the repository, what's probably going on here is that the config option `remote.origin.mirror` is set.  You can confirm this by running `git config remote.origin.mirror`, which will show you `true` if it's set.

The easiest thing to do in this case is to run `git config --unset remote.origin.mirror` to turn this option off and then try your push again.  Unfortunately, there isn't a useful `--no-mirror` option to turn this off for you.

Comment: Thanks brian. That was helpful. I updated my post with the results I got after following your answer. As my push is getting rejected, there was a push to the master repository after I mirrored it at my local desktop. However, there wasn't any push to the `Single_home_page` branch and I am wondering why it's still complaining because I am trying to push it to `Single_home_page` branch and not to the `master` branch.

Comment: The answer there is that you need to use `git push -f` (or put a `+` in front of the branch name).  You've rewritten history with bfg, so your local changes aren't considered a strict superset of what's on the server.

Comment: It looks like the forced update worked (please see my updated post) when I used `+` before the branch name. I didn't use `-f` though.But I didin't see any commit related message on the gitlab when I checked the repository. What could be the reason?

Comment: When you use bfg to rewrite history, it doesn't change the commit message, but it does change the hashes of the objects involved.  So you'll still see the same changes as before, but they'll have different SHA-1 values than before.

Comment: One more question. Instead of pushing the mirrored repository to `Single_home_page` branch, if I decide to push it to a newly created branch/repository/project on gitlab or github, is it going to push `master` branch and associated history as well to the new repository?

Comment: You can specify the branches to be pushed. If you only specify certain branches, only those will be pushed.

Comment: It will push to whatever remote you set, by default, as the master or main branch.  That's why I always take master/main to do this.  It has every commit, tags, and branch.  IMO. Just did this today.

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer for those who has cloned --mirror repo and still want to push a new branch to the original repo.

Disclaimer: Mirror repo is not supposed to have local changes and in theory, it is not advised to push modifications to the original repo.  But in case, for some reason, you still want to do it, follow the answer.

---

Create a worktree where we can access all files easily

```
git worktree add <path>
cd <path>

# you should be able to see all the files.
# you can change and commit here... 

# now, we can't push to a mirror repo, or technically to the remote url with mirror=true. 
# so we create another remote 

git remote add nomirror <.git url>
# nomirror is just a name... 

git push nomirror HEAD:<branchname>
```