# --mirror can't be combined with refspecs when trying to delete files in git history

Tags: git, gitlab, git-filter-repo

My gitlab repository is too big so I want to delete every file that is greater than 300KB in the gitlab history.

I'm following this tutorial https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/reducing_the_repo_size_using_git.html

The commands I used:

```
git clone --bare --mirror https://my/gitlab/repo.git

cd my_repo

git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 300K

git push origin --force 'refs/heads/*'
```

the last command returns `fatal: --mirror can't be combined with refspecs`

I'm not that experienced in git but I think I'm literally just following the instructions and
it's not working. Any idea why?

(The repo contains only the master branch and it's not protected)

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49325013/error-mirror-cant-be-combined-with-refspecs