# How to clone from a repository and bring all remote branches using git?

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs, git-clone

I Have repository 'A', I cloned from it to Repository 'B' using ***git clone http://example/A.git**.*
So now, I have one local branch "master" and all other branches as remote branches in 'B'.

Next Step, I want to clone from 'B' to a new Repository 'C' using ***git clone --bare***, and bring all remote branches from 'B' and make them as local at 'C'.

[Image of My Workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YU1D7.png)

Answer (score 0):

just clone B to C

and run

`git branch -a`

to see all hidden branches

You can see full details in this answer:

[How to clone all remote branches in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-to-clone-all-remote-branches-in-git)

Comment: I don't have a problem showing the branches using git branch -a OR -r. the problem is, when you clone a repository without using --bare(Repo B), and then you clone B to C using --bare you can't see all branches. my question is how to bring the branches from B to C (known B is non-bare and C is bare(

Comment: Have a look on the link provided in my answer:

if you want to work on that branch, you'll need to create a local tracking branch which is done automatically by:

`git checkout experimental`

Comment: Can we do it without checking out to the wanted branch? so like only from the clone command ? I will add to the question a workflow please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mirror clone, but a mirror clone is a bare clone (for good reasons).  That is:

```
[host B] git clone --mirror http://example/A.git
```

produces a mirror clone on B, and you can now do `git clone --bare` from `B` to `C`:

```
[host C] git clone --bare <url of B.git>
```

The mirror clone on B will contain *all* references that A gave, while the bare clone on C will contain only the *branch and tag* references from A.  That is, if repository A has references `refs/heads/master`, `refs/heads/develop`, `refs/remotes/origin/master`, `refs/replace/a23456789a23456789a23456789a23456789`, and `refs/tags/v1.0`, the mirror on B has all these same references, while the bare clone on C lacks the `refs/remotes/origin/master` and `refs/replace/...` reference.

At any point after each clone, you can create `refs/heads/` references within the clone.  Hence if you want a non-bare repository on B, you can replace the *middle* step with:

```
[host B] git clone http://example/A.git
```

followed by a series of `git update-ref` (for arbitrary reference names) or `git branch` (for `refs/heads/*` reference names) operations.  But note that the B clone at this point has copied neither A's `refs/remotes/origin/master` nor A's `refs/replace/...` reference.  B has:

- A's `refs/heads/master`, which B calls `refs/remotes/origin/master` now
- A's `refs/heads/develop`, which B calls `refs/remotes/origin/develop` now
- A's `refs/tags/v1.0`, which B calls `refs/tags/v1.0`

That is, B has copied A's `refs/heads/*` (branch) references, but has *renamed* them to be *remote-tracking names* instead of branch names.  B has copied A's tags without any name changes.

As the last step of its clone operation, B ran `git checkout master` (or maybe `git checkout develop` if A told it to use `develop` instead).  This has created B's only branch name, `refs/heads/master` (or maybe `refs/heads/develop`) and populated B's index and work-tree.  So if you would like to make `B` have, as branches, all the branches that `A` had, it's relatively easy:

```
for all branches that were in A, but are now remote-tracking names in B:
    create branch in B using the remote-tracking name we created during the clone
```

which you can express in whatever programming language you prefer.

There is one annoyance here, which is that the "create branch" step will fail for the one branch that was *already* created by the `git checkout` step at the end of `git clone`.  To avoid the annoyance, either check for and skip that branch, or use `git clone --no-checkout` to avoid creating the branch and populating the index and work-tree on `B`.

#### Summary

- If you want a *bare* clone on B, using `--mirror` is an option.  You will get *all* references.
- If you want a bare clone on B but not a mirror, use `--bare`.  You will get all branch and tag references.
- If you want a *non-bare* clone on B, you must work harder (see above).

Repeat this for C.