# When I clone my repository in my local system then it will show only one branch

Tags: git, github, branch, git-clone

I have two branches:
 1. Master
 2. Staging

All my commit available in staging branch but in master branch it have only necessary commit which I push using cherry-pick from staging branch.

Now the issue is, I have re-set up this repository in my local machine but when I clone this repo using `git clone https:repository-url.git` then it will create only one master branch and only appear master branch commit so how can I also clone my staging branch and their commit?

I already try to `git checkout -b staging` but it will make a copy from master branch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone all remote branches in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-to-clone-all-remote-branches-in-git)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+all+branches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git branch -r` will show you all the local copies of the remote branches, such as `origin/master` and `origin/staging`. Just run `git checkout staging` (without the `-b`!) to create a local `staging` branch that tracks the remote one.