# How to checkout to sub branch in git

Tags: html, git, github, terminal

I have cloned an ongoing sample project repo from git and its main branch is 'master'. But this repo has all changes uptodate in branch 'develop' and only a 'README.md' file in  'master' branch. I got the master branch cloned using https. I need to get the changes in 'develop' branch. Please help me to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

This command fetches all branches from remote.
`git pull --all`

This command checkouts the requested branch (if it is present)
`git checkout develop`

Also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72156/11065438) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292359/11065438)

Comment: This partially helped to solve my problem by using 'git checkout develop'. Initially when I tried to do so, I got detached state which confused me. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

> But this repo has all changes uptodate in branch '`develop`' and only a '`README.md`' file in '`master`' branch

Then clone *directly* the right branch with [`git clone -b`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---branchltnamegt):

```
git clone -b develop https://url/of/repo
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to merge changes from the develop branch to the master branch. Have a look at https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-merge to see if that helps.

Comment: Basically Im not trying to merge, but trying to get the checkout to develop branch to get the changes. I don't need want to merge this to master branch

Answer (score 0):

When you download a git repo from say GitHub it is defaulted to `master`. To view a new branch you can `checkout` to a branch.

Assuming you know the git basics

```
git checkout <branch-name>
```

So you should be doing

```
git checkout develop
```

**Extra**
To view all remote branches

```
git branch -r
```

To list your local branches

```
git branch
```

To pull changes from `remote` to your `working tree`

```
git pull #pull downloads "all" by default
```

To only download all the changes in remote but not to your working tree (the branches you're tracking)

```
git fetch
```

Comment: This is really very informative. Thanks for the help.