# Does GitHub provide a way to download the full project for hosting in another place?

Tags: git, github

I currently have some private projects in GitHub.

Recently I've set up a server for hosting an indefinite amount of projects, without any cost other than the server itself.

Those projects have multiple branches and commits, and I want to copy all of this to my new server.

Is there a way to download the project with branches, commits, pull requests, etc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone all remote branches in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-to-clone-all-remote-branches-in-git)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+all+branches

Comment: Did you install a source code hosting program on your new server? If so, which is it (name/version)?

Comment: @kelvin I've installed the latest git on my Ubuntu server. Up, running and tested

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just found exactly what I wanted:

1. github.com homepage, logged in
2. Settings > Account
3. Export account data

**Warning**: This downloads all the data of all your repositories you ever collaborated.

This was exactly what I wanted: to download all my repositories and spin them up in another place.

Hope to help somebody in the future trying to migrate their repositories

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git clone` to do what you want. This will get all of the commits and branches from your GitHub project. It will **not** include Pull Requests.

Answer (score 0):

Github, like many git host propose you a way to do it : The fork. The point is to start a new git starting as a copy of the first one. Bonus : you will be able to merge what you done on the new git to the source one with a merge request. You will be able to do it by creating a new git repository and set the git you want to fork as a upstream.

The other way is to clone the git you want on your local machine, then push it to a new one. It is closer to a copy because in this case the two git repositories (old one and the copy) will be fully independents. More information [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/duplicating-a-repository).

Comment: Forking is a GitHub feature. It is not a core feature of Git itself.