# How can I push all branches from a Git bundle I received?

Tags: git, import, git-bundle

I got a Git bundle (`client.bundle`) with several branches that I need to import in my project. I was able to import a single branch by cloning it locally, changing the remote URL and pushing it. However I can't push the other branches.

```
$ git clone ./client.bundle project1
$ cd project1
$ git remote set-url origin git@my.git:username/myrepo1.git
$ git push -u --all
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
```

Now I have:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@my.git:username/myrepo1.git (fetch)
origin  git@my.git:username/myrepo1.git (push)
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/branch2
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/branch3
```

**Note**: The last four branches `remotes/...` show up in RED!

When I try to push another branch I get an error:

```
$ git push origin branch3
error: src refspec branch3 does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@my.git:username/myrepo1.git'
```

How can I push them all?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+src+refspec+does+not+match+any

Comment: You don't appear to have a local branch named `branch3`. You have a *remote* branch named `branch3` associated with your `origin` remote.

Comment: @phd Thanks. Does this mean the bundle did come with a remote "branch3", or not? If it came with it, I need to push it to the new repository. I'm sorry I still can't see clearly.

Comment: It came with its own local branch `branch3`; `git clone` made it remote. See how to clone all branches: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67699/7976758

Comment: @phd Thanks again. That helps a lot. The bundle comes with 15 branches, so I guess I have to work on it one by one.