# Bitbucket Repository Branches Cloning Issue

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-bash

I have a Bitbucket repository with many branches.
I need to migrate the Bitbucket repo with and all branches to Github.

I cloned the repository locally through the git bash command:
`git clone https://newuserme@bitbucket.org/newuserme/bb101repo.git`

It seems that not all associated branches are copied/cloned locally.

When I check local branches (`git branch -l`), I can see master and few branches only, not all other branches and I'm only able to migrate few branches to the Github repository.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Possibly related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-to-clone-all-remote-branches-in-git

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone all remote branches in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-to-clone-all-remote-branches-in-git)