# Remote branch not visible in local repo

Tags: git

I have a remote Git (Github) repo. I cloned it using the `git clone` command. but when I try to see the branches Using the `git branch` command it only shows one branch, 'main',while there is at least 15+ branches on the remote repo, which are visible via the command `git branch -r`. How can I get my all the remote branches into my local repo?

Comment: If you can see them with `git branch -a` (or `-r`) then they exist in your local repository. You can reference them by their full name, e.g. `origin/somebranch`. If you want to switch to a remote branch, use `git switch branchname` (without `origin/`)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72156/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+all+branches

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to not "pollute" your local branch namespace with *all* the remote tracking branches.

Using `git branch -avv`, you will see both local (main) and remote tracking branches (`origin/xxx`).
You can use the ["guess mode" of `git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt---guess) to create a local branch which will have its corresponding remote branch as upstream.

```
git switch <branch>
```

> If `<branch>` is not found, but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to
>
> ```
> git switch -c <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
> ```