# Git: search all commit messages, branch names, commit contents, in one command

Tags: git, git-log

I want to search across all possible refs (commits/branches/tags), all commit messages, all branch names, and all commit contents.

Comment: A useful preliminary step is first clone all remote branches: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68582362/565877

Comment: Not in one command, but with an alias to chain commands, yes. But I guess this would be out of your question scope?

Comment: I don't really mind what the implementation is, just want to easily search everything stored in git. In fact, I fully expect this is necessary, given the request to search _ev_er_ry_thing_

Comment: How does what you want differ from searching through `git log -p --all`?

Comment: `git log -p --all` is a totally valid strategy for doing this search! See below answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Since noone suggested a chain of commands yet, and in case you did not craft it yourself already :

```
git config alias.findall '!f() { echo -e "\nFound in refs:\n"; git for-each-ref refs/ | grep $1; echo -e "\nFound in commit messages:\n"; git log --all --oneline --grep="$1"; echo -e "\nFound in commit contents:\n"; git log --all --oneline -S "$1"; }; f'
```

It chains these three commands :

```
# for branches and tags we use for-each-ref and pipe the result to grep
git for-each-ref refs/ | grep $1

# for commit messages we use the grep option for log
git log --all --oneline --grep="$1"

# and for commit contents, the log command has the -S option
git log --all --oneline -S "$1"
```

So now you can just do

```
git findall something
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try printing everything to the terminal, and then searching output with your terminal application:

```
git log -5000 -p --all --decorate --oneline --graph
```

For performance reasons, this is limited to 5,000 commits.

[image: sample output from command]

There's a bit more noise/information than originally requested, but this can be beneficial - for example, you can now search commit hashes, timestamps, author names. You can intuitively search for deleted files, etc.

You could include `--oneline` if performance is an issue. It causes author and date information to be omitted:

[image: diff of oneline]

Comment: You have not understood the question. Neither original nor useful in this context.

Comment: I just realized this is not completely off-base, but missing some CRUCIAL points tying it back to original question. I've edited this answer to connect back to the original request in my question.

Comment: It would be really nifty to pipe this output into some sort of search tool, but my command line skills are not there yet