# Change user on all commits in Git repository

Tags: git

Having dug out a Git repository for an old project of mine and cloned it onto my current machine, my attempt to load it into my Git GUI failed. The error indicated that there are too many contributors on the project since I'm a hobbyist using a hobby licence. This is a private project so I am in fact the one and only user and the licence is entirely appropriate, but `git log | grep Author: | sort -u` reveals that I seem to have used about half a dozen email addresses over the years. Presumably that's what's causing the block.

I found an article on the web indicating that users can be retrospectively changed using the following:

```
$ git filter-branch --env-filter '
OLD_EMAIL="oldname@olddomain.com"
NEW_NAME="New Name"
NEW_EMAIL="newname@newdomain.com"
if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
  export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$NEW_NAME"
  export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$NEW_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
  export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$NEW_NAME"
  export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$NEW_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

That *seemed* to make the changes, but I still get the same error when trying to load the repository into the GUI so I guess it's somehow incomplete.

Is there some sort of nuclear option that will force Git to completely change all commits to the same user? There are no concerns about rewriting history as there have never been any other users.

[edit] The GUI client in question is SmartGit, which now has a license for hobby use. It can be used on any repository with a single committer/author.

Comment: i wouldn't rewrite history like that - i'd change your git client

Comment: A hobby license for what?

Comment: Maybe the GUI detects the old commits from some untouched refs like `refs/remotes/origin/*`. It seems `git filter-branch` only touches `refs/heads/*` and `refs/tags/*`.

Comment: If you don't care about the history (as it seems from your question) just create a shallow clone instead (or, as many others already suggested, switch to a client with no such stupid restrictions).

Comment: After you run `git filter-branch`, the original refs are still visible in `refs/original`. Most likely, your GUI picks up those refs.

Comment: @Jim Redmond Question updated.

Comment: @ElpieKay Can I delete such untouched refs? I'm afraid I'm not very familiar with Git's CLI.

Comment: @tripleee I don't care about preserving the author IDs (in fact I'd prefer to tidy them up by changing them all to the mail address I'm currently using). I don't want to lose the commit and branch history though. 

Switching to another client would be an option I suppose, if I can find another that I like. I switched from GitKraken some years ago when they introduced restrictions on personal use, I don't know if there are other nice alternatives without such restrictions. Would welcome recommendations.

Comment: @Blackmyre https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis

Comment: @Blackmyre Try a new clone from the current local repo to another new local repo, `git clone /path/to/repo -- /path/to/new`, and then load `/path/to/new` into the GUI.

Comment: @ElpieKay Aha! That seens to do it. It doesn't seem to have preserved the branches, which is a pity, but not the end of the world. If you post as an answer I'll mark it as the solution (if you know of a way to keep all branches that would be better still).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-do-i-clone-all-remote-branches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the GUI detects the old commits on the untouched refs like `refs/remotes/origin/foo` and rejects the loading. So, one of the ideas is to make a new clone from the current local repo, and make it contain only the updated branches and tags.

```
git clone /path/to/repo -- /path/to/new
cd /path/to/new

# Since it's not a bare/mirror clone,
# the branches are refs/remotes/origin/* instead of refs/heads/*.

# Go into detached HEAD in order to avoid failure in the following fetch
git checkout -d HEAD

# Fetch and create branches in refs/heads/*
git fetch origin +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*

# Edit the remote "origin" if there is a real remote repository
# The current "origin" points to /path/to/repo
git remote set-url origin <the_remote_repository_URL>

# Go back to a branch
git switch <branch>
```

If there is a real remote repository, make sure you run `git push -f` to update the branches/tags in the remote repository before `git fetch` or `git pull`. Otherwise, the GUI would complain once the old commits are fetched into the new local repository.

Comment: To expand on this, there seem to be three tasks required: 
  Strip authors, using the git filter-branch approach described in the question.
  Import branches, using the git fetch approach described in this answer.
  Re-clone to another local repository to get rid of the problem untouched refs.

The order of these steps matters. If branches are imported after stripping authors, the authors are restored. If the repository is re-cloned after stripping authors, the branches can't then be imported. I had to add branches first, then strip authors, then re-clone, then add branches again.