# How to Git clone and fetch all branches from a GitHub repository to my local machine?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-clone

I'm trying to clone all branches from a GitHub repository to my local machine using Git. I want to have local copies of all branches, not just the default branch.

I've tried the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/abdurrahimcs50/Django-Boilerplate-Project.git
cd Django-Boilerplate-Project
git fetch --all
```

Then, for each remote branch, I tried to create a local tracking branch using this loop:

```bash
for branch in `git branch -r | grep -v HEAD`;do
    git checkout --track $branch || true
done
```

I expected that after running these commands, I would have local copies of all branches. However, when I list the branches using `git branch`, only the default branch is listed. The other branches are listed when I use `git branch --all`, but they are prefixed with `remotes/origin/`, indicating that they are remote tracking branches, not local branches.

What am I doing wrong? How can I clone and download all branches from a GitHub repository to my local machine?

Comment: What happens if you remove `|| true`?

Comment: Try some really simple debugging like `echo $branch` and I think you'll see the issue which is solved by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4754797/283366) in the nominated duplicate

Comment: This seems like a misunderstanding of what a branch is. All branches from the remote are included with the original clone by default.

Comment: I think what @Phil was hinting at is `$branch` here vs. `"${branch##*/}"` in the linked answer. i.e., executing `git checkout --track remotes/origin/thebranch` vs. `git checkout --track thebranch` if I understand correctly.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do
`git fetch --all` to fetch all the branches from the remote repository

and then
`git checkout <remote branch name>` to switch to the specific branch you want to work on.

Comment: That's what they tried to do in a script and for some reason it didn't work.

Comment: This is how it works for me, isn't it good? https://prnt.sc/tRax6MV8zSjg

Comment: That's not what `fetch --all` means. `git fetch` already fetches all branches.